# Can we use directed broadcast as limited broadcast? See scenario below

Tags: networking, routes, broadcast

I am learning Computer Networks and was reading about limited and directed broadcast.

If a host with IP *200.100.1.1* wants to send packets to all host **in the same network**, then does the procedures ***A*** and ***B***, to achieve our goal, differs?

**Procedure A** `SRC- 200.100.1.1 DEST- 200.100.1.255`

**Procedure B** `SRC- 200.100.1.1 DEST- 255.255.255.255`

So, can we use ***Procedure A*** to do the task required as the directed broadcast(destination) is aiming at its own network? Or ***Procedure A*** is incorrect and ***Procedure B*** is the right way to go.

Comment: It would be much nicer to put the specific text into the question that future individuals will be able to more easily find and understand the problem.

Comment: @KevinO edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IP directed broadcast packets have a destination IP address that is a valid broadcast address for the **subnet** that is the target of the directed broadcast (the target subnet). The intent of an IP directed broadcast is to flood the target subnet with the broadcast packets **without broadcasting to the entire network**. [reference; emphasis added](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/ip-directed-broadcast-ex-series.html)

Assume the following:

- We have an IP address of `200.100.1.1` (`11001000.01100100.00000001 .00000001`)
- The netmask is `/24` (or 255.255.255.0) (`11111111.11111111.11111111 .00000000`)

Then:

The network address is a bitwise *AND* between these two:

```
11001000.01100100.00000001 .00000001
11111111.11111111.11111111 .00000000
=
11001000.01100100.00000001 .00000000
200      100      1         0
```

So we know the network is `200.100.1.0`.

To determine the broadcast address, we **invert** the subnet mask and *OR* it with the network address.

```
Network:          11001000.01100100.00000001 .00000000
Inverted Netmask: 00000000.00000000.00000000 .11111111
                  11001000.01100100.00000001 .11111111
                =
                  200      100      1         255
```

The broadcast for 200.100.1.0/24 will be on 200.100.1.255

We also know that this network will have 254 possible hosts in it (or 253 given a gateway address; and the assumption that .0 is not addressable so 200.100.1.1 -> 200.100.1.254).

Comment: This question was already asked on [networkengineering.se], and I pointed the OP to [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) that explains it all, but he decided to ask here.

Comment: @RonMaupin, thanks for the info! Not sure if I should delete this answer, but the one you referenced is very comprehensive and colorful!

Comment: I would leave the (correct) answer, but the question deserves to be closed. It seems to be asked by someone too lazy to do the work to actually understand.

Comment: See, lazy. He wanted the answer handed to him, rather than learn how to do it for himself. I tried to create an answer that explains "_everything you wanted to know about IP addressing, but were afraid to ask._:

Comment: @RonMaupin with due respect, I am not great in Computer Networks as you are. I am a sophomore who does not have good mentors(who sometimes mislead students), I am trying my best to understand things. I have read that link as well. Thank you.

Comment: @SushantGiri, the answer I pointed you to was one of the simplest and best explanations of how to do this that you will find anywhere. If you cannot read, understand it, and figure this out on your own, then you are studying the wrong thing. If someone answers your question for you, it does neither party any good because you didn't really learn how to do it, and when confronted with the same thing in the future, you will not know how to work out the correct answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sir, the only reason that I asked this question is because, our mentor forced us to go with the _procedure B_ as his logic was " **to broadcast messages in the same network we use limited broadcast, which is 255.255.255.255** " and wasn't convinced even if me and my classmates did the **exact calculation** to calculate broadcast address.